# jquery добавить в скрипт зависимость от ширины вюпорта

Tags: jquery, viewport

Есть скрипт - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NBqOeE. Скрипт копирует мейн меню сайта когда до него доходит скролл, и делает копированное меню фиксед, если докрутить назад на место копированное меню пропадает. Делаю адаптив сайта, этот скрипт надо отключить на определенном вюпорте. 
Нужно: на всех экранах меньше 768 пикселей(768 включительно) что бы этот скрипт не работал, если мы опять изменим вюпорт на 768+ что бы опять работал. Спасибо

```
// Create a clone of the menu, right next to original.
$('.menu').addClass('original').clone().insertAfter('.menu').addClass('cloned').css('position','fixed').css('top','0').css('margin-top','0').css('z-index','500').removeClass('original').hide();

scrollIntervalID = setInterval(stickIt, 10);


function stickIt() {

  var orgElementPos = $('.original').offset();
  orgElementTop = orgElementPos.top;               

  if ($(window).scrollTop() >= (orgElementTop)) {
    // scrolled past the original position; now only show the cloned, sticky element.

    // Cloned element should always have same left position and width as original element.     
    orgElement = $('.original');
    coordsOrgElement = orgElement.offset();
    leftOrgElement = coordsOrgElement.left;  
    widthOrgElement = orgElement.css('width');
    $('.cloned').css('left',leftOrgElement+'px').css('top',0).css('width',widthOrgElement).show();
    $('.original').css('visibility','hidden');
  } else {
    // not scrolled past the menu; only show the original menu.
    $('.cloned').hide();
    $('.original').css('visibility','visible');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Можно так.** Таймаут указан в 100ms, можете изменять под ваши нужды. В вашем случае и 1000ms будет в самый раз.

```js
var resizeTimeout;

window.onresize = function(){
 clearTimeout(resizeTimeout);
 resizeTimeout = setTimeout(initAfterResize, 100);
};

function initAfterResize(){
 
 window.ScreenWidth = $(window).width();
 window.ScreenHeight = $(window).height();
 
 if (window.innerWidth < 768) {
  // не выполняем
 }
 else {
  // выполняем
 }
 
}
```

Comment: извиняюсь за наглость, не могли бы Вы, связать Ваш ответ с моим скриптом? ( я еще новичек), а нужен срочный результат.

Comment: сам разобрался, по другому способу, но спасибо. Ваш на ресайз тоже рабочий